# How to print intermediate result of commands in a pipeline?

Tags: command-line, pipe, console, tee

I have a series of commands running through a pipeline like this:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
```

How can I print the intermediate result of `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3`? I know I can use the `tee` command to print the result to a file. But is it possible to just print it to the console? This is for debugging purpose as my actual commands are very complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `tee` to the current terminal:

```
cmd1 | tee /dev/tty | cmd2 | tee /dev/tty | cmd3 | tee /dev/tty | cmd4
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Do you know is it possible to let tee's print result on its own line?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. Do you want to be able to distinguish the output from multiple `tee`s, or distinguish the `tee`d output from `cmd4`’s output?

Comment: I want to be able to distinguish the output from multiple tees.

Comment: I think that should be possible by redirecting `tee`’s extra output to new file descriptors, and then decorating those outputs with `ts` or something similar, but my shell-fu in that area is weak.